# access elements of external html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a file (html) and I want to grab everything in one of the classes. Both of these files are on my computer, and offline. I need to somehow use this file as `document`, I guess. I can then get all content in my `class` attribute.

I found this online but I doesn't seem to work.

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {   
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {   
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {   
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                console.log(allText)
                return allText;
            }   
        }   
    }   
    rawFile.send(null);
}
var x = readTextFile("~/repos/ranjs/source.htm")
```

would this possibly work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var class = $('.class').load('/filepath/file.html');
});
```

Comment: You can do it local using localhost. Because AJAX need to make HTTP request which need a server.

Comment: please elaborate or answer. I just started using javascript

Comment: From your code, you write `    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();`  that is means you want to make HTTP Request. and to achieve that you need a server in your machine which called a localhost. so all you need to solve you problem is to install a localhost for example you can use XAMPP https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: is there no better way?

Comment: "is there no better way". That _is_ the way that web pages are hosted -using a webserver. If your PC has Windows you can use IIS or Apache. If you have Mac or Linux, then Apache is the main choice, although there's also nginx and one or two others.